# How do I change file creation time in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

I'm wondering how I can change file creation time within C#?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can use the following [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setcreationtime.aspx) from `System.IO` namespace:

```
File.SetCreationTime(fileName, fileTime);
```