# change data in Image Details tab properties C#

Tags: c#, .net

[Image Detail](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/690/0cw7.jpg)

For example I want to insert "Ferrari" in Title field: How can I manage it in c#

Comment: This is information added to the file structure itself. You'll need to study the `JPG` file structure and then manipulate the bytes by hand.

Comment: Go and read more about FileInfo and File class under System.IO

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This article will help you. You have to download one package and use it in your application.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bb887b05-2018-4978-b115-c8c98e3542ce/setting-file-infoattributes-author-subject-?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I thought its good to let me read the complete detail and understand purpose and how to do it.

Comment: @Nil23 I agree with Barth. This answer may not be useful at some point if the link changes. You should probably copy the important parts of that page here.

Comment: I got it and I will take care of this in future. Thanks for suggesting this and I completely appreciate your opinion.

Comment: This option does not work for images. I've already tryed it.

Answer (score 2):

There are various types of information in that "properties" window. I have personally categorised and addressed these as follow:

- **Basic file information** - Name, size, date created modified, etc. These fields are applied to every file regardless of the type of the file. They are stored as part of the file structure (eg NTFS defines them). Most of them are going to be changed through the "System.IO" namespace. If, for example, you wanted to change the created date of a file - you can [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589677/how-do-i-change-file-creation-time-in-c). Search for what you want to change and likely someone else has already asked about it.
- **Basic Image Fields** - These are things like the image height, width, pixel depth, etc. I separated these out because they are part of the image definition itself and are based on how the image is created and saved. If you wanted to change them you are going to have to reformat the image.
- **Image File Information** - This includes the title, subject, rating, tags, comments, etc. From what I can tell these are stored inside of the file but the location may vary based on the type of the image file (JPEG is going to store differently than BMP). If you want to edit one of these fields you might consider using the "Windows.Storage.FileProperties.ImageProperties" namespace. If you are using WIC (Windows Imaging Component), you should consider using the BitmapMetadata object to access these fields.
- **Image Metadata** - This is probably one of the most complicated parts of an image. These include EXIF, Geocode and other fields that are saved in the file by the hardware. Some of the fields are manufacturer specific (maker notes) and other fields are pretty standard. I would strongly recommend reading through the EXIF specification before you begin to try to change these fields (http://www.media.mit.edu/pia/Research/deepview/exif.html). The next place to go for these is to start using the "GetPropertyItem" routine which can be called on a System.Drawing.Bitmap object.

I know this is a lot to take in but hopefully one of these sets you on the right track. Good luck!