# Delete file if it was created last month

Tags: c#, fileinfo

I have a program that keeps a diary for each day in the current month, the problem I have is when I start a new month all the appointments for last month are still there because they are saved in a txt file, like this

3, 8.30am, Dentist, description

The first field above it the day, as you can see the month is not present.
The code below is what I've tried, it compiles without errors.

My question is will this work??
I don't know how to check it, because any file i create now will be a new file and I don't have any old file??

*What I want is, when the program loads if this month is for example Feb and the file was created in Jan, delete that file and create a new empty file*

```
  bool checkFileExists(string file)
  {
     if (!System.IO.File.Exists(file))
     {

        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(file))
        {
           // File created.
           return true;
        }
     }

     else
     {
           FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);
           if (fi.CreationTime < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1))
              fi.Delete();
     }
           // File exists.
           return true;
  }
```

Comment: To verify if the code works properly, you can always change the creation time of your test file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589677/how-do-i-change-file-creation-time-in-c

Comment: Try changing the `if` statement from `if (fi.CreationTime < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1))` to `if (fi.CreationTime.Month < DateTime.Now.Month)`

Comment: thats cool, I didn't know that was possible, thanks

Comment: This smells like bad design. Can you change the file-formatto include year and month?

Comment: If only, No I cant change it, it has to be in that exact format.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Can you store the information about which month the file refers to somewhere else? Perhaps in a different file, or perhaps as part of the filename?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`File.GetCreationTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getcreationtime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

So taking your code from above it would become:

```
bool checkFileExists(string file)
{
 if (!System.IO.File.Exists(file))
 {
    using (FileStream fs = File.Create(file))
    {
       // File created.
       return true;
    }
 }
 else
 {
       if (File.GetCreationTime(file) < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1))
          File.Delete(file);
 }
 // File exists.
 return true;
}
```